# How to disable clipboard for cutting command like dd, daw etc, but keep for commands like yy, yaw etc?

Tags: vim, neovim

**Problem:**

I started to use Neovim. I like the flexibility of removing characters; however, it does not work with the following flow I have always used.

Let's say I want to change the image source on `<img src="image1.png">`

1. I open a browser and copy the URL on Imgur, so in the OS system buffer, I have now `https://imgur.com/a/xxxxx`
2. I edit `index.html` and press `di"` to delete inside quotes and then want to paste my URL, but I can't cause my clipboard just changed to `image1.png`.
3. So I have to go to the browser again, copy the URL, and paste it into Neovim.

How can I turn off such clipboarding? If I need clarification on something conceptually, please point me the right way. Appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I turn off such clipboarding?

You don't. You learn to use it properly, as well as the rest of the editor.

In this case, you would do:

```
vi"p
```

if you have either `unnamed` or `unnamedplus` in `:help clipboard`, or either of:

```
vi""+p
vi""*p
```

if you don't, depending on how you copied the URL in your browser.

- `vi"` visually selects the content of a quoted string, see `:help v`, `:help i"`, and more generally `:help motion.txt`.
- `[reg]p` puts from the given register…

  - `p` alone puts from the `""` ("unnamed")register, see `:help quotequote`,
  - `"+p` puts from the `"+` ("clipboard") register, see `:help quoteplus`,
  - `"*p` puts from the `"*` ("primary") register, see `:help quotestar`.

Also, the last thing you yanked is always in register `"0`.

NOTE: it is possible that Neovim handles things a bit differently than Vim under the hood but I don't use it so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this in the general case, but you can use the blackhole register with `"_`.  From the documentation:

> When writing to this register, nothing happens.  This can be used to delete
> text without affecting the normal registers.  When reading from this register,
> nothing is returned.

So instead of `di"`, you can do `"_di"`, and then you won't modify the default register values.

In my particular case, I've mapped `<Leader>d` to `"_d` (with `:noremap <Leader>d "_d`), so I can type `<Leader>di"` and get the desired behaviour.